# Is there a Java Future implementation that will execute in caller thread if pool is busy?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

We use `ExecutorService` to make various REST calls to cloud storage in parallel, and we are concerned that the pool can become busy with blocked calls that have run amok, and then block newer calls for a long time (cloud timeouts can be several minutes after going through all of the retries).  Of course we can always add more and more threads, but one solution I've implemented in C++ is to have `Future.get()` run in the caller thread if the task has not yet started. Java *almost* does this with `Executors.newWorkStealingQueue()`, but the run-in-caller logic is only enabled if the caller is itself a pool thread:

```
class ForkJoinTask {
  private int awaitDone(...) {
      ...
      if ((t = Thread.currentThread()) instanceof ForkJoinWorkerThread) {
        // execute in caller thread
```

This is how work-stealing keeps recursive algos from running out of threads.  But if the caller is a normal thread this logic isn't triggered. `ForkJoinPool` is no different, because  `Executors.newWorkStealingQueue()` is just a wrapper around that. Is there anything in Java supports what I'm after?

PS: We can't use JDK 21 with its virtual threads yet :-(

UPDATE: A little more explanation about the use case.  We find that in order to answer certain questions about cloud storage like "should this path be treated as a directory or a file", we have to ask several questions:

- Does a blob exist with that name?
- Does a blob exist with that name followed by a / ?
- Do other blobs exist that have that path as a prefix?

The executor lets us ask these questions in parallel and reduce the latency.  So we have a shared executor for everyone to ask these questions of the cloud storage endpoints.  BUT... occasionally one of the endpoints will freakout and not answer questions until it either recovers or times out, which can take several minutes.  When this happens, we don't want the delayed requests to clog the executor for everyone else and make *every* request wait.  The "caller executes when busy" pattern gives us a safety valve, everything runs a little slower for a few minutes but not a *lot* slower.

Comment: Perhaps using [virtual threads](https://openjdk.org/jeps/444) might help. No pooling, a fresh new thread for each task.

Comment: I would love to use virtual threads, but aren't they Java 21?

Comment: Yes, Java 21+ has virtual threads. Version 21 is the latest long-term support (LTS) version.

Comment: Note that this work-stealing in `ForkJoinTask` does not imply that the caller works on the task it’s waiting for. It might be an entirely unrelated task which bears some dangers 1) an inherited thread context not intended for this task, 2) this thread might still be busy processing some other task long after the task it’s actually waiting for completed, 3) insanely deep stack traces, even with the risk of `StackOverflowError`. And Virtual Threads are indeed the solution to those problems. Let’s hope that Java 21 becomes commonplace soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use standard ThreadPoolExecutor, "CallerRuns" policy does exactly what you want:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy.html

From Javadoc:

> A handler for rejected tasks that runs the rejected task directly in
> the calling thread of the execute method, unless the executor has been
> shut down, in which case the task is discarded.

Here is an explanation about how rejection happens:

> Any BlockingQueue may be used to transfer and hold submitted tasks.
> The use of this queue interacts with pool sizing:
>
> - If fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, the Executor always    prefers adding a new thread rather than queuing.
> - If corePoolSize or more threads are running, the Executor always prefers queuing a request rather than adding a new thread.
> - If a request cannot be queued, a new thread is created unless this would exceed maximumPoolSize, in which case, the task will be
>   rejected.

UPDATE FROM OP: use SynchronousQueue to avoid queueing and it works like a charm

```
exec = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,new SynchronousQueue<>());
exec.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
```

Comment: Ooh, that could be it!  But I'm unclear under what circumstances is a task "rejected"?  If I configure the limit to be equal to the number of threads, will it basically reject tasks when the pool is busy?

Comment: The task will be rejected once the task queue hits the limit and new thread could not be created

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment on your approach, rather than an answer to your question.

---

> one solution I've implemented in C++ is to have Future.get() run in the caller thread if the task has not yet started.

OK, but according to the normal meaning of "future," each `Future` object must be associated with one, and *only one* task. So, suppose you have a collection of `Futures`, and you pick one, and you call `f.get()`. OK, there's three things that could happen;

1. You picked `f` corresponding to a task that has not yet started, so now, `f.get()` will perform the task, and not return until it's complete.
2. You picked `f` corresponding to one of those "blocked calls that have run amok." The task already has started, and so `f.get()` can't do anything else but wait for it to complete.
3. You got lucky, you picked `f` corresponding to a task that has finished, and `f.get()` can immediately return the result.

Is that what you had in mind? The problem that I see is that in case (1) and in case (2) there might be *other* `Future` objects in your collection corresponding to tasks that already have completed. Those results are sitting there, and your "caller thread" isn't dealing with them because it's either doing a task (case 1) or it's sitting idle waiting for a result (case 2), when it could be clearing the deck of completed results.

In a nutshell, I'm questioning whether `Future` is the right solution to your problem. `Future` is a good solution when you've got a lot of unrelated bits of code that all are submitting tasks to the same shared thread pool. It lets each client wait for its own, and *only* its own task results.

But, if there's really only one client—if all of the tasks in the pool were submitted for the same reason, then maybe there's a better way. Maybe you can structure the program to prioritize whatever it is that your program does with those results—make it happen as soon and as smoothly as possible. For example, instead of returning results via `Future`, why not have each task stuff its result into a queue? Then you can be sure that the "caller" thread will never be blocked trying to `take` a result from the queue if there is any result available to be taken.

Comment: There are multiple clients performing what *should* be short tasks, but occasionally one of the cloud endpoints will freak out for a few minutes.  If all tasks for that endpoint fill the executor, then everything else has to wait for the freakout to finish.  At least with "caller executes", the task will finish slightly slower rather than block, which is acceptable.  We could also make a Map<Endpoint,Executor> and that would be better but seems like overkill for this case.  I don't expect the freaked-out tasks to finish any faster, I just don't want them ruining everyone's day